# How to plot an array in physical distance coordinates with an inhomogeneous resolution

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation

**The issue**

I want to treat some data from a simulation of a 64*30 (in the XZ plane) cloudy atmosphere.

Specifically, I want to display an image of some physical property, e.g. the extinction, as a function of position (in physical distance units (km), not in "number of x points, number of z points" / "pixel" coordinates, if this isn't clear, it will be further with an example).

- I have the horizontal resolution : 55m
- I know that the vertical axis goes from 0 to 1000m. The vertical resolution is not constant, it doubles within the cloud layer (since we want more precision).
- Namely : z ∈ [0,400]m, the resolution is 50m, i.e. from index z[0]to z[9] - below the cloud
  z ∈ [400,850]m, the resolution is 25m i.e. from index z[9] to z[26] - inside the cloud 
  z ∈ [850,1000]m, the resolution is 50m again, i.e. from index z[26] to z[29] - above the cloud

The problem is basically displaying an array in an irregular grid. I don't know what's the most efficient way to do it. 
Are there any methods that I didn't thought about ?

**What I did** 
My data is organized as :

```
X1 Z1 EXTINCTION ... other parameters ...
X1 Z2 EXTINCTION ... other parameters ...
 .
 .
 .
X1 Z30 EXTINCTION ...other parameters ...
X2 Z1 EXTINCTION ...other parameters ...
 .
 .
 .
X64 Z30 EXTINCTION ...other parameters ...
```

I have stored the value of extinction at each line in some array `EXT`, as well as the x and z coordinates at each line in `X`& `Z`

Next, I added the values of `EXT` to a 64*30 matrix representing my coordinates in space.
I used 2 in range loop to follow the order the line index in my data, which is represented by k.

```
Extinction = np.zeros(64,30)
k = 0 #count the line
for x in range (0,64): 
        for z in range(0,30) : 
            Extinction [x,z] = EXT[k]  #Add the value of extinction for the corresponding x,z position     
            k += 1 #next line
```

Finally, I use `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow` to display the result

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(Extinction.T,cmap='gnuplot',origin='lower')
```

Since I want my axis to show the distance in meters, knowing the resolution and the number of pixels, I just use :
`extent(55*64,0,1000)` as an argument in `ax.imshow()`

*Of course, the resulting plot is only correct for a constant vertical resolution. Extent()only stretches homogeneously the plot. Since the resolution goes from 50m to 25m, the height won't be correct.*.
[Basic plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yH8M4.png)


**"Brute force" method**

I have tried to go to what seems the *easy* way. I'm not sure whether it is correct or not. 
I modified my `Extinction` array by artificially doubling the number of points outside the cloud (essentially doubling the resolution). I did that so the vertical resolution is constant everywhere. My thought process is that, since the extinction coeficient is always 0 in the air anyway, it shouldn't be a problem. I did the following :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Alebdo = np.zeros(64,30)
k = 0
for x in range (0,64): 
        for z in range(0,17): #below the cloud
            Extinction[x,z] = 0 
        k += 9 #we doubled each line. The line number corresponding the beginning of the cloud is 9     
        
        for z in range(17,36): #cloudy zone
            Extinction[x,z] = EXT[k]     
            k += 1
        
        for z in range(36,40): #above the cloud
            Extinction[x,z] = 0     
        k += 2
```

This seems to work, but :

1. The cloud layer is a bit "squeezed"
2. I don't know if it is "correct" physically
3. Some properties (unlike the albedo or the extinction) aren't constant below the cloud. So I can't just seperate the cloud layer from the air and put a constant value everywhere else. For example, the radiance field will not be homogeneous below the cloud.
4. This is not very practical as I have to manually change a lot of parameter depending on the simulation I use.

["Brute-force"/manual edit of the array plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1VXe.png)

**Interpolation**

I didn't use interpolate a lot before. But from my understanding, it is powerful in these kind of cases with an irregular grid :

```
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

xg = np.linspace(0,64,41)
zg = np.arange(0,30,1)
xgrid, zgrid = np.meshgrid(xg, zg)
EXT_interpolate = griddata((X, Z), EXT, (xgrid, zgrid), method='nearest')

im=ax.imshow(xgrid, zgrid, EXT_interpolate, cmap='gnuplot')
f=fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax,shrink=0.8)
```

My issues :

1. My graph shows the data in "array index" coordinates. How do I show the distance in meters ? I can't simply use `extent()` as before, is there any equivalent for `contourf` ?
2. Where should I interpolate my data ? It would make sense to use 41 vertical points (as this is the number of points I have when the resolution is 25m : 40*25m = 1000m & add the level z=0).
   [Interpolated plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV8e7.png)


   **EDIT :**
   Thanks to the comment from Paul Brodersen, I chose to interpolate :

```
#X was previously a list of index : X=[1,2,3....,64] 
#I changed it to distances in km since I know the resolution is 55m X=[0,0.055,0.110 ,...]
#Same for Z, which is now Z=[0,0.050,0.0100,0.0150, ..., 0.350,0.400,0.425,0.450,...]
# So it now accounts for the change in resolution

from scipy.interpolate import griddata

#Grid on which we will interpolate
xg = np.linspace(0,3.465,0.055) #don't touch the x resolution
zg = np.arange(0,1,100)#change z resolution so that it's uniform, 10m here.
xgrid, zgrid = np.meshgrid(xg, zg)
EXT_interpolate = griddata((X, Z), EXT, (xgrid, zgrid), method='nearest')

#Plot the interpolation
im=ax.imshow(xgrid, zgrid, EXT_interpolate, cmap='gnuplot2')
f=fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax,shrink=0.8)

#I still have to add extent(0,3.465,0,1) if I want to display distances and not the index of my grid points
```

Comment: W.r.t. 1) Simply convert your x, z "array" coordinates to physical coordinates first.

Comment: W.r.t. 2) Either you use an interpolated grid that is a superset of the original grid, or you use a grid that is much, much finer than the original grid. You only run into issues if the original and the interpolated grid are about equally fine/dense and are offset from one another in any of the dimensions.

Comment: If you want to indicate the difference in resolution at the different z values, you could consider using `method='nearest'`. That should reproduce the "basic" plot, albeit with correct x, z values (assuming you have already translated the array coordinates into physical coordinates).

Comment: @PaulBrodersen Thanks ! I edited my post, the changes in my code are at the end of it. Is that what you meant by "convert your x, z "array" coordinates to physical coordinates" ? I still have to use `extent()` to show the distance in the axis... Also, you said that the interpolated grid should be quite finer. While making that grid finer by rising the resolution in the z-axis makes sense (since it is not the same everywhere along the grid and I have to do it anyway), rising the resolution in the x-axis seems wrong, since it's feels like we have better precision on the data. Is that correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [pcolormesh](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolormesh.html) documentation

> Create a pseudocolor plot with a non-regular rectangular grid.

[image]

Code below is longer than you need because I want to show you how the shading options change the way the axes limits are interpreted.

Also, for `shading='flat'` you must pass a "smaller" color matrix, I just removed the last row, column, you would perform some sort of mean/interpolation.

Eventually, the grid lines are there to show that the gridding is irregular, in production you'll probably remove the `ec='w', lw=0.1, antialiased=1` arguments

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import show, subplots
from numpy import arange, concatenate, cos, meshgrid

x = 55.0*arange(64)
z = concatenate((
    0.00 + 50*arange( 8),
    400. + 25*arange(18),
    850. + 50*arange( 4),
))
X, Z = meshgrid(x, z)
E = cos((X/3000-Z/1200)) # unimportant

fig, ((none, flat), (nearest, gouraud)) = subplots(2, 2, figsize=(11,4.5), layout='constrained')

none.pcolormesh(X, Z, E, shading=None, ec='w', lw=0.2, antialiased=1)
none.set_aspect(1)
none.set_title('No shading')

flat.pcolormesh(X, Z, E[:-1,:-1], shading='flat', ec='w', lw=0.2, antialiased=1)
flat.set_aspect(1)
flat.set_title('Flat shading')

nearest.pcolormesh(X, Z, E, shading='nearest', ec='w', lw=0.2, antialiased=1)
nearest.set_aspect(1)
nearest.set_title('Nearest shading')

gouraud.pcolormesh(X, Z, E, shading='gouraud', ec='w', lw=0.2, antialiased=1)
gouraud.set_aspect(1)
gouraud.set_title('Gouraud shading')

show()
```